# Вопрос о потоках Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как определить, какой из двух потоков закончил свою работу последним.

```
   public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Chicken c = new Chicken();
            Egg e = new Egg();
            Thread chicken = new Thread(c);
            Thread egg = new Thread(e);
            chicken.setName("ch");
            egg.setName("egg");
            chicken.start();
            egg.start();

        }
    }

    class Chicken implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for (int i = 0; i <6 ; i++) {
               try{
                   Thread.sleep(460);
               }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                System.out.println("Chicken is frist ");
            }
        }
    }

    class Egg implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for (int i = 0; i <6 ; i++) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(460);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                System.out.println("Egg is frist ");
            }
        }
    }
```

egg или chicken.

Comment: Передайте в конструктор колбек и вызывайте его по завершению потока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите именно узнать кто завершится первым, то как ответили вам в комментах вопроса, передайте колбэк и вызывайте его или передайте copyonwrite list и записывайте в него сообщения. А если вас это интересует как бы с точки зрения интервью, то бишь без запуска кода и его модификации, то на это вопрос нет ответа, выполнение потоков не детерминированно, и по-этому может выполниться первым как первый так и второй поток